# CMake: Change C_INCLUDES in flags.make

Tags: cmake, iar

I am using Windows 7 and CMake 3.5 with Cross-Compiling. For compiling I use the IAR 78000 C-Compiler V3.34A/W32 (very old). The include files where added over `include_directories()` to `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`.

The Compiler needs:

```
C_INCLUDES = -IC:/foo/bar/
```

But CMake creats in the flags.make file only:

```
C_INCLUDES = -IC:/foo/bar (without Backslash at the end)
```

I tried:

```
get_directory_property(cmake_include_directories INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
set(include_dirs)
foreach(it ${cmake_include_directories})
    set(include_dirs ${include_dirs} "${it}/")
endforeach()
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${include_dirs}")        
#set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}.hex  PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${include_dirs})
message(STATUS "New Dir: ${include_dirs}")
```

But the values in `include_dir` will not override the values in `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`

Is it possible to change my `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` only for the `C_INCLUDES`, to have the desired format?

Update: The solution for my problem

```
get_directory_property(cmake_include_directories INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
foreach(iterationValue ${cmake_include_directories})

set(iterationValue ${iterationValue}////) # You need //// for one /!

target_include_directories(
   ${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
   ${iterationValue}
   )

endforeach()
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you *sure* the compiler must have a trailing slash? What happens otherwise?

Comment: Otherwise I got the error Error[2]: Failed to open #include file 'in78000.h'. wIth #include "in78000.h". The error could be removed by #include "/in78000.h" which I think is not very nice and also in Eclipse I cant use a feature! I write will write the solution for my problem in the question above